# Node JS Async/Await

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am getting an Unhandled promise rejection.

I am simply trying to await for the function insertParams to finish before calling res.send().

Here is what I have tried:

```
app.get('/', async (req, res) => {
    let queries = {hello: 'testing'};
    const paramResult = await insertParams(queries)
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      })
    res.send('Hello world!');
});

async function insertParams(params) {
    return db.collection('params').insertOne(params, (error, success) => {
        if (error) {
            console.log('Error: ' + error);
        }
        else {
            console.log('Success: ' + success);
        }
    })
}
```

The full error:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:13601) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Comment: `insertOne` uses a callback, not a Promise

Comment: So I do not need await at all?

Comment: The code will execute in order?

Comment: No, you need to work with the callback - convert it to a Promise if you want to `await` it

Comment: Would you mind explaining with a bit of code? That would help me a lot...thanks!

Comment: Read the linked canonical

Comment: 1) You're mixing promises & async/await syntax. This is why it gets confusing. 2) `insertParams()` doesn't look like it do anything special. It can be straight replaced by `insertOne()`. Is there a reason why you need `insertParams()`? This is because 3) [`insertOne()` returns a Promise](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.2/api/Collection.html#insertOne) in newer node driver versions.

Answer (score 4):

According to [insertOne()](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.2/api/Collection.html#insertOne)

> **Returns:**
>
> Promise if no callback passed

So, you can simply return the `Promise` without passing in the `callback`

```
app.get('/', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        let queries = {hello: 'testing'};
        const paramResult = await insertParams(queries);

        // the `paramResult` will be of type `insertWriteOpResultObject`
        console.log(paramResult); 

        res.send('Hello world!');
    } catch(err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
});

function insertParams(params) {
    // no callback needed
    let promise = db.collection('params').insertOne(params);

    return promise;
}
```

However, the returned `Promise` resolves to [`insertWriteOpResultObject`](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.2/api/Collection.html#~insertOneWriteOpResult)

Which has the following properties, please see reference link for more detail

```
{
    insertedCount:  Number  
    ops:            Array.<object>  
    insertedIds:    Object.<Number, ObjectId>   
    connection:     object  
    result:         object
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
app.get('/', async (req, res) => {
  let queries = {
    hello: 'testing'
  };
  // 3. You should use `try catch` to handle `await` error.
  try {
    // 4. The return is the value that the `Promise` resolved.
    const success = await insertParams(queries);
    res.send('Hello world!');
  } catch (err) {
    // 5. Handle error here.
    console.log(err);
  }
});

// 1. You should not use `async` without `await`.
function insertParams(params) {
  // 2. You should make callback to `Promise`.
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    db.collection('params').insertOne(params, (error, success) => {
      if (error) {
        reject(error);
        return;
      }
      resolve(success);
    });
  });
}
```

If using [node-mongodb-native](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native), just return without callback:

```
function insertParams(params) {
  // It will return `Promise`
  return db.collection('params').insertOne(params);
}
```

Comment: Doesn't this database have a built-in promise interface that should be used rather than doing your own promisifying?

Comment: @jfriend00 yes, of course. But, it did not mention which driver it was using. if using [node-mongodb-native](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native), just return without callback.